# How to iterate over multiple lists of a dicts in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I need to create directories for repositories with Ansible. Paths should be like:

```
./centos/6/repo1/x86_64/
./centos/7/repo1/x86_64/
./rhel/7/repo2/noarch/
```

So combinations of distribution name, major release version, repo name and base arch could be arbitrary, and no extra directories would be created.
It looks like Ansible file module is suitable for this job, so I create a list of variables with this kind of structure:

```
repos:
    - name: repo1
        os_list:
          - centos
          - rhel
        major_distribution_list:
          - 6
          - 7
          - 8    
        archs:
          - noarch
          - x86_64
```

Now I'm stuck trying to find a right loop control.
**with_items** only allows me to iterate through key-value pairs, not list elements.
**with_subelements** is a bit more handy, but it only lets me use one of the lists/subelements, while I need two and more:

```
    - name: Create dirs
        file:
          dest: './centos/7/{{ item[0].name }}/{{ item[1] | default("noarch") }}'
          state: directory
        loop:  '{{ repos | subelements("archs") }}'
```

This is the best I can get of **with_subelements**.
**with_nested** does combine as many elements as I like, but I can't find a way to feed it with the lists from the variable. The best I can do with it is to create the whole bunch of possible directories regardless of which are actually needed:

```
   - name: Create dirs
       file:
         dest: '/centos/{{ item[2] }}/{{ item[0].name }}/{{ item[1] | default("noarch") }}'
         state: directory
     with_nested:
       -  '{{ repos }}'
       -  [x86_64, noarch]
       -  [6, 7]
```

**with_cartesian** seems to be pretty much the same.

## So the question is:

is there a way to use a complex variable with multiple lists and combine them all in one task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to loop *include_tasks*. The play below

```
vars:
  repos:
    - name: repo1
      os_list:
        - centos
        - rhel
      major_distribution_list:
        - 6
        - 7
        - 8    
      archs:
        - noarch
        - x86_64
tasks:
  - include_tasks: repo-paths.yml
    loop: "{{ repos }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: repo
...

# cat repo-paths.yml
- debug: msg="./{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}/{{ item.2 }}/{{ item.3 }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ repo.os_list }}"
    - "{{ repo.major_distribution_list }}"
    - "{{ repo.name }}"
    - "{{ repo.archs }}"
```

gives:

```
"msg": "./centos/6/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./centos/6/repo1/x86_64"
"msg": "./centos/7/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./centos/7/repo1/x86_64"
"msg": "./centos/8/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./centos/8/repo1/x86_64"
"msg": "./rhel/6/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./rhel/6/repo1/x86_64"
"msg": "./rhel/7/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./rhel/7/repo1/x86_64"
"msg": "./rhel/8/repo1/noarch"
"msg": "./rhel/8/repo1/x86_64"
```

Comment: Nice solution but it would be better to use the recommended newer `loop` syntax (since Ansible 2.5) in both parts of solution, rather than older `with_items` in 2nd part.  And for extra points, mention the old syntax briefly with pointer to [this section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.5.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop) of the Ansible 2.5 porting guide.

Comment: @RichVel: What's preventing you from posting your answer (if you think it's better)?

Comment: Your answer is fine, as I mentioned - I was making a small suggestion to improve it.

Comment: @RichVel: I know, my answer was accepted and upvoted. Still the same, what's preventing you from posting your answer, even a small one, with the details of your improvement. (if you think it's better)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping you should create nested dict files.

For eg.

os:
  centos:
    - 
  rhel:
    -

This way you can control the loop per os and per distribution.

Also my suggestion would be use some values from ansible facts

Variables like os name, os major distribution, architecture can be easily taken from ansible facts which will reduce the dict creation and implementing the ansible module would be easy

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Facts are not applicable here as directories are created based on repo properties, not the target system properties.